# javascript edit html on the fly

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am working with a web application (Sharepoint), that I need to make some adjustments inline with. The application itself is very powerful, but some areas have limitations. For instance, in this instance I am trying to create an onlick event for a photo. Due to the limitations, I cannot accomplish this. (if you know sharepoint, you know wiki page limitations) So, my goal is to actually implement javascript on the page (supported) that will locate the images, and insert the onclick event.

The issue I am running into is that I cannot seem to even get a simple search and replace to work. Most examples seem to refer to a text node, but I am not familiar with that that terminology is.

I am looking for some guidance. Thanks!

---

(This is not answer, but comments are too short)
I am trying to solve a couple issues.  Here is one of those.  I have a document library in one site, and it's embedded in another site.  When a user clicks a document it renders the document inside the very small window of the document library.  One of the things I want to accomplish is adding a "target=_blank" to the url to open in an entire new browser window.   Unfortunately, this document list is dynamic, so the it has to be done on the fly.  The second challenge is an image, as a mentioned.   In this occasion, there's a tiny little selector arrow which refreshes data into another web part. While this works, it would be much more convenient to click on the image. Again, the content is dynamic, and in this situation I need to read the URL from the arrow, and dynamic change the image to be clickable.   This may be outside of my capabilities, because I'm not strong with web development practices.  I much more a compiler kind of guy. ;)   I do not have any code examples to provide as everything I have tried is just proof of concept.  I will take another look at this with some of the suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are trying to edit the HTML with JavaScript to add an event handler.  This isn't normally the way you want to interact with the DOM to add an event handler.

The simplest thing would be to use jQuery and use it to find the element with the appropriate selector and add the event handler.  I've used this previously on SharePoint projects without any issues.

Something along the lines of the line would be a place to start (albeit the selector causes a click event handler to all img tags in the DOM).

$('img').click(function(){/*your code here when clicked*/});

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid jQuery, something like this could work great:

```
function search(scope, tagName, attr, query) {
    tagName = scope.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var size = tagName.length;
    var results = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (tagName[i].getAttribute(attr) == query)
            results.push(tagName[i]);
    }
    return results;
};
```

The above function does a cross-browser query of whichever scope you pass to it.  So, if we wish to search for all images within the document that have 'Clickable' as their class, we can do the following:

```
var images = search(document, 'img', 'className', 'Clickable');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = onClickFunction; // onClickFunction being whatever you write.
}
```